# Why is $ \ \int^x_{x_0} v\frac{dv}{dx} \, dx =\int^v_{v_0} v \, dv$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $$\int^x_{x_0} v\frac{dv}{dx} \, dx =\int^v_{v_0} v \, dv$$

where $v$ is a function of $x$, and $x$ is a function of time $t$?

I know it involves some substitution, but which one?   The only thing I see is letting $\ dx=dv/\frac{dv}{dx} \ $ but why are we allowed to "just define" $dx$ to equal that?

---

$ $

$ $

$ $

[image]

Comment: Rather sloppy notations. Where is this identity from?

Comment: The leading $v$ is not relevant; the point is that an integral of a function of $v$ times $dv/dx$, integrated $dx$, is the same as integrating that same function of $v$ in $dv$. This is the change of variables formula, which is basically a consequence of the chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: My textbook, : ( it's trying to derive the equation of kinetic energy from this.

Comment: $u=v(t)$ and $du=v'(t)\,dt$.  Then, $\int_{x_0}^x v(t)\,v'(t)\,dt=\int_{v_0}^v u\,du$.

Comment: Whoah there. Which of these letters are functions, which are variables, and which functions depend on which variables?

Comment: @user7530 I've added the relevant page from by textbook.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: My answer had a typo; it said "free variable" at a point where it should have said "bound variable". I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us be clear on the meanings of "free variable" and "bound variable".

$$
\sum_{j=1}^4 j^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = \sum_{k=1}^4 k^2.
$$
The variables $j$ and $k$ above are bound variables. One can freely change the name of a bound variable from $j$ to $k.$ The value of the sum $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2$ does not depend on the value of anything called $j$ or $k.$ On the other hand the value of
$$
\sum_{j=1}^4 \cos(j\ell)
$$
depends on what number $\ell$ is. So $\ell$ is a free variable in this expression.

The chain rule says that if $h(x) = g(v(x))$ then $h'(x) = f'(v(x))v'(x).$ Therefore
$$
\int_a^b f'(v(x))v'(x)\, dx =\int_a^b h'(x) \, dx = h(b) - h(a) = \underbrace{f(v(b)) - f(v(a)) = \int_{v(a)}^{v(b)} f'(v) \, dv}.
$$
In the integral over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}},$ $v$ is a bound variable and we can rename it freely. We could just as correctly have written
$$
f(v(b)) - f(v(a)) = \int_{v(b)}^{v(a)} f'(w)\, dw.
$$
We are not "just defining" $dx$ that way; we are "just defining" $dv$ that way, and we could have equally correctly called in $dw.$

What justifies integration by substitution is the chain rule. The chain rule is differentiation by substitution. For example in
$$
y = (x^3 - 5x+ 12)^{40},
$$
one can use the substitution $u = x^3 - 5x+12$ and then write
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} = 40u^{39} \cdot (3x^2 - 5) = 40(x^3 - 5x + 9)^{39}\cdot (3x^2 - 5).
$$

Comment: Thanks!  I also found a similar thread here with a really nice answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554051/swapping-differentials-rigorously?rq=1 $ $ $ $ $ $ It's all clear for me now!

Comment: Basically, the key is seeing $v$ (as defined in my OP)  as the derivative of some other function, say $y(v)$, then all starts making sense via the chain rule!

Answer (score 1):

This is a substitution problem. You have gone from an $x$ variable to $ v$ variable. Limits of integration change as a result. As $ x $ goes from $ x_0 $  to $x_1$ , $v$ goes from $v_0$ to $v_1$.

Comment: What is the process that brings us from the first integrand to the second integrand?

Comment: v is a  differentiable function of x, therefore dv=(dv/dx)dx.

Answer (score 0):

The notation here is atrocious; presumably what is meant on the left is
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} v(x) \frac{dv}{dx}(x)\,dx,$$
with $v$ a diffeomorphism on $(x_0,x_1)$. We can introduce the new variable $y = v(x);\ dy = \frac{dv}{dx}dx$ and make the substitution
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} v(x) \frac{dv}{dx}(x)\,dx = \int_{v(x_0)}^{v(x_1)} y \,dy.$$

Comment: I don't see any explicit mention of the chain rule here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy There's no explicit mention of *anything* here. Why are $x$ and $v$ both in the limits of integration and in the integrand? Why is $v$ a function on the left and a variable on the right? The above is the only way I can make sense of the OP, but if you think my interpretation of the expressions in the OP are incorrect, feel free to take your own stab.

Comment: I've uploaded a screen of the page from by book - maybe I omitted to mention something crucial (in which case sorry for the confusion...)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyD5F.jpg

Comment: @user7530 : I never thought your interpretation was incorrect, nor anything else in your answer. I said you answer doesn't mention the chain rule; you responded that your answer doesn't mention _anything_. My point is the chain rule is at the heart of all this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry, I thought you were saying the *question* doesn't mention the chain rule. In any case my assumption (perhaps incorrect) is that the main issue is in interpreting what the textbook author intended, and not the basic mechanics of changing variables.